# Can't install a pod (Mixpanel) via CocoaPods - Fails to compile (file not found) - Bridging header issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, mixpanel

I'm trying to update my project's version of Mixpanel to use Cocoapods, as it was previously installed manually. I already was using Cocoapods, so I assumed it would have been an easy update to just add `pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.9'` to the Podfile and run `pod install`. After doing this, I am getting the following errors:

***At the import statement `#import "Mixpanel.h"`***

`/Users/timc/ios/app/MyApp/Classes/AnalyticsUtil.h:10:9: 'Mixpanel.h' file not found`

***And also this one***

`Failed to import bridging header '/Users/timc/ios/app/MyApp/Classes/MyApp-Free-Bridging-Header.h'`

I'm trying to import Mixpanel into an Objective-C file. My **Podfile** looks like this...

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 2.1'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.9'
end

target 'MyApp Tests' do

end

target 'WatchKit Extension' do
    pod "Mixpanel/AppExtension"
end

target 'WatchKit App' do
    pod "Mixpanel/AppExtension"
end

target 'MyAppSharedFramework' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 2.1'
end
```

So what do I need so my project can find the Mixpanel source files? I've tried using #import  and while that allows me to *option-click* to navigate to the right file, the project still fails to build.

I'm running Xcode 7.2, and project is a mix of Objective-C and a bit of Swift.

Happy to provide any further information to help diagnose this issue!

Comment: timgcarlson you have issue in workspace                                                            rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able fix this issue by removing the workspace and regenerating it.

```
rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install
```

So clearly something with my workspace was corrupted... this resolved it.