# CocoaPods Bridging Header file not found

Tags: swift, cocoapods, objc-bridging-header

New developer here, and I'm currently building an app in swift. We are using cocoapods, but after running pod install, we get an error in the objective-c bridging header saying that the file cannot be found, but for any and every file in our bridging header. For example, we use DateTools. We pod install it, in the bridging header we put: 
    `#import <DateTools/DateTools.h>`
but then, upon running, it errors, saying that `'Datetools/Datetools.h' file not found`. I've already looked through a lot of other similar posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341655/cant-install-a-pod-mixpanel-via-cocoapods-fails-to-compile-file-not-found), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377450/cocoapods-1-0-header-files-not-found)), but none have solved the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that you use frameworks and instead of importing it into the brdging header, why not try just doing a plain `import` at the top of your class instead?

Comment: In the podfile, we do have use_frameworks!. When I remove the bridging header, it errors at the import and says something like `No such module "Parse"`

Comment: with pods we dont use bridging headers at all

Comment: the whole joke behind pods is, that we don't have to bridge the headers, since cocoapods does the this work for us

Comment: thanks for the accept. i have upvoted your question. hope you're getting your code working. good luck with your project

Comment: also i have answered your other question

Comment: No thank you man. Code is working great, but I'm learning firebase right now so I will be asking many more questions haha

Comment: okay dude. always glad to help. but let me tell you. it is important that you upvote AND accept answers. people are investing their time here and here is everything about upvotes and accepts...

Comment: just telling you, because you are new

Comment: I actually did, but I didn't have the 15 prestige necessary for it to show. Just got my 15th, so happy to upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the `use_frameworks`! instruction in Cocoapods, the bridging header is not required for importing Objective-C pods in Swift.

Simply set your desired pods into your podfile:

```
#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
#Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'YourProject' do

#Swift Pods
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'ActiveLabel'

#ObjC Pods
pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser'
pod 'Firebase'

#This stuff is to set the SWIFT_VERSION
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
end
```

Run `pod install`. Run `pod update` (should not be necessary, but for some reason I'm getting updates almost every time, even after clean install). Close Xcode and reopen using the white `xcworkspace` file.

[image]

```
import Alamofire
import ActiveLabel 
import IDMPhotoBrowser
import Firebase
```

Done.